# A Node with only private IP in a vpc can not connect to other node in other vpc

Tags: terraform, amazon-eks, amazon-vpc, vpc, aws-vpc-peering

**Problem**:

My eks residing in a vpc can not connect to other redis service residing in another vpc with port number: 6379.

**Things I have done so far**:

I have created a eks cluster with the following vpc configs:

```
module "vpc" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version = "3.2.0"

  name                 = "test-vpc"
  cidr                 = "10.0.0.0/16"
  azs                  = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names
  private_subnets      = ["10.0.1.0/24", "10.0.2.0/24", "10.0.3.0/24"]
  public_subnets       = ["10.0.4.0/24", "10.0.5.0/24", "10.0.6.0/24"]
  enable_nat_gateway   = true
  single_nat_gateway   = true
  enable_dns_hostnames = true

  tags = {
    "kubernetes.io/cluster/${local.cluster_name}" = "shared"
  }

  public_subnet_tags = {
    "kubernetes.io/cluster/${local.cluster_name}" = "shared"
    "kubernetes.io/role/elb"                      = "1"
  }

  private_subnet_tags = {
    "kubernetes.io/cluster/${local.cluster_name}" = "shared"
    "kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb"             = "1"
  }
}
```

And made peering connection:

```
resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection" "vpc_peering" {
  peer_vpc_id = "target_vpc_id"
  vpc_id      = module.vpc.vpc_id
  auto_accept = true
  accepter {
    allow_remote_vpc_dns_resolution = true
  }

  requester {
    allow_remote_vpc_dns_resolution = true
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "VPC Peering between ${module.vpc.name} and Miso Default"
  }
}
```

After this, I manually added route with target_vpc cidr as destination to private route table of newly created vpc above, and similarly added route with the newly created vpc cidr as the destination.

Then i realized I need to check network acl of target_vpc and it has the following inbound rules and seems normal:

```
Rulle Number        Type         Source         Status
100              All Traffic   0.0.0.0/0        Allow
```

Then I realized i need to add add another security group to `target_vpc` that allows all tcp connection on port 6379 from the nat gateway of the newly created vpc.

After those all things i have done If i deploy a pod that connects to redis in target_vpc on port 6379 connection fails with code:
`CONNECTIONTIMEDOUT`

Am I missing something here?
I appreciate any comment that might help me.
Thanks

Comment: What does redis config looks like?

Comment: Probably, redis is only listening on the localhost port: 127.0.0.1:6379.

You need to configure redis to bind on 0.0.0.0.

Comment: lambda functions in other vpcs can connect to  redis in `target_vpc`. And also there is a security group that points to target_vpc and has inbound rule with redis port allowing new vpc cidr

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the problem.
Redis server inside *target_vpc* had a security group that did not have CIDR block of new vpc and it was blocking the traffic.